# Script is asking to define a cell as a variable

Tags: excel, vba

Previously this sub I created ran smoothly, however it is now giving me an error that the cell is not defined as a variable.

These particular lines of code find highlighted cells and deletes them.

[image: the cell is not defined as a variable.]

```
Columns("C").Select
For Each cell In Selection
    If cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow Then
    cell.Delete
End If
Next
```

Comment: so define it? Please do not post pictures of your code. Post the actual code and explain which line is highlighted when you get the error.

Comment: Thanks.   I updated to include the code, the compiler indicates the error it is in ```` For each cell in selection ```` and it specifically highlights cell as the variable that is not defined - cell is not a variable to be defined, it is just referring to each cell is to be selected

Comment: You are using it as a variable. Name it something else, and define it.

Comment: The way you think it works is not how it works.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Defined cell as range